# Can I get event Pokemon into my game card even if my 3DS is broken?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire, nintendo-network-id

My 3DS got wet and I'll have to wait until the end of the month to get it fixed due to money issues, meanwhile the Legendary Pokemon distribution event is going on and soon the codes for the Legendary birds will be distributed, and I really want to get those Pokemon.

Can I use my friend's 3DS to get these Pokemon with my game card to get them? Or is my game card linked to my broken 3DS? Do I need a 3DS linked to my Nintendo Id Network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem about it. You can use your Pokemon game in another 3DS and type your codes to obtain your Pokemons.

The game is not linked to any 3DS console or Nintendo ID. It can be linked to a Pokemon Global Link account, but it does not matter, as you don't need it to use a code (and as it is linked to your game, and not a 3DS console).

Comment: I was wondering if the game or the PGL would check my game card against the system, I'll try later in the weeked

Comment: It should be noted that this only works with the physical game cards. The digital downloads from the eShop ARE tied to your Nintendo Network ID, which can only exist on ONE system in the 3DS family at one time. If you need to use a different system for digital downloads, you'll have to transfer you ID. A guide can be found here: http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14169/p/430